# Django: Unsupported lookup 'following' for CharField or join on the field not permitted

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I try to build follow system, when I tried to let the users see the posts of the users which that follow them I got error Unsupported lookup 'following' for CharField or join on the field not permitted

The profiles model

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True
    )
    following = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name="follow"
    )
```

The posts model

```
class Video(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='post-videos')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

my view

```
class home_screen_view(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logged_in_user = request.user
        post = Video.objects.filter(
            author__username__following__in=[logged_in_user.id]
        ).order_by('-created_date')
        context = {
            'post_list': post,
        }
        return render(request, "personal/home.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `post = ...` query is wrong because you are retrieving the author's `username` (which exists), but then treating it as if this field were a foreign key or m2m with a property following, which is flat out wrong. username is a CharField.

Instead let's try to clarify the concepts that will be useful to making our solution:

Each Video, has an author.

Each author, is a user.

Each user has an m2m relationship `following` which is the users he follows.

Each user has a REVERSE m2m relationship `follow` which is the users that follow him.

Therefore in your view, your query should be:

```py
    post = Video.objects.filter(
        author__follow=logged_in_user
    ).order_by('-created_date')
```

With django M2Ms, so long as the logged_in_user is in that list, `...follow=logged_in_user` will return true and filter the item in.